# Is there any difference between using PureComponent and shallowCompare addon?

Tags: reactjs

What's the difference between these examples?

```
class MyPureComponent extends React.PureComponent {
}
```

and

```
import shallowCompare from 'react-addons-shallow-compare'`

class MyPureComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the official Documentation:**

`shallowCompare` is a helper function to achieve the same functionality as `PureComponent` while using ES6 classes with React.

If your React component's render function is "pure" (in other words, it renders the same result given the same props and state), you can use this helper function for a performance boost in some cases.

Example:

```
var shallowCompare = require('react-addons-shallow-compare');
export class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={this.props.className}>foo</div>;
  }
}
```

`shallowCompare` performs a shallow equality check on the `current props` and `nextProps` objects as well as the current state and `nextState` objects.
It does this by `iterating on the keys of the objects being compared and returning true when the values of a key in each object are not strictly equal`.

`shallowCompare` returns true if the shallow comparison for props or state fails and therefore the component should update.
`shallowCompare` returns false if the `shallow comparison` for props and `state` both pass and therefore the component does not need to `update`.